# How to conduct am A/B test for a feature which cannot be accessed by every visitor?

Tags: self-study, ab-test

I am prepping for an interview and here is one of the questions I have come across:

`How would you conduct an A/B test on an opt-in feature?`

I think you cannot perform a "fair" test with an opt-in option.  People viewing the A version of the site will come from the whole distribution of users whereas people viewing B will only come from the set who have opted in.  This seems to violate the conditions for a controlled experiment.

What is your take on this?

Comment: What is opt-in ? As far as I know, opt-in means that the user has actively agreed e.g. on using his email address for newsletter purpose. Given that, does the question refer to a test for a feature only opt-in users can see ?

Comment: @steffen - Yes, I assume the question means you only see the test feature if you have previously opted-in.

Answer (score 3):

**Regarding your statement**

You are correct: If the test shall compare an opt-in version of a site to a non-opt-in-version, then one cannot perform a fair test. Since visitors how have opted-in are probably more engaged than regular users, I'd expect the group of opt-in visitors to outperform the other group in engagement related metrics as long as meaningful versions are compared (although such a test may uncover that the opt-in version is not good enough). It might even be that the metrics for different versions are not comparable at all (because of different goals).

**Another interpretation of the interview question**

<sub>Since you have used the [self-study-tag](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), I'd provide some starting points for further thinking instead of a complete answer (I can answer them myself if requested though, otherwise I suggest that you provide an answer to your own question).</sub>

Here are two more interpretations of the interview question

1. How to conduct an A/B-Test for a feature that shall lead to an opt-in (i.e. the visitors have not opted in yet but the feature shall make them do so) ? This would be a more standard A/B-Test setup so I guess it is unlikely the question was meant this way.
2. How to conduct an A/B-Test restricted to test *different versions of an opt-in feature*. This would be my first guess how the question is meant (more complicated). So let's focus on this one.

So how to conduct an A/B-Test for the second case ? Consider that the site with the opt-in feature can be in an restricted area (i.e. you have to e.g. log in to get there) or can be just a different version of a site every visitor can access (e.g. the homepage).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  Upon re-reading of the question, I think my original interpretation was wrong and your interpretations seems much more like it.